RF Receiver Shuffles Data
I’m experiencing an unexpected issue with my receiver.
I’m using the DL-RXC2016BH receiver module along with an RF transmitter (I also tested the setup with different receivers, but the results remained exactly the same). I’ve confirmed that the transmitter is functioning correctly because another device, which relies on the exact data I’m transmitting, reacts as expected when I send this data. Additionally, the device has a remote button with eV1527 encoder and an RF Transmitter, and data I get from it also has the same problem. I read the transmitted data using the code below:
#define DATA_PIN 4

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(DATA_PIN, INPUT);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Listening for eV1527 data...");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("GO");
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long receivedData = 0;  // Variable to store the received 24-bit data
  if (readEV1527Signal(receivedData)) {
    Serial.print("Received 24-bit Data: ");
    Serial.println(receivedData, BIN);  // Print in binary
    Serial.print("Decimal Value: ");
    Serial.println(receivedData, DEC); // Print in decimal
    delay(1000);
  }
}

// Function to decode eV1527 signal
bool readEV1527Signal(unsigned long &data) {
  data = 0;
  int i = 0;
  const unsigned int maxCount = 24;
  unsigned long highDurations[maxCount];
  unsigned long lowDurations[maxCount];

  unsigned long highDurationBeginning = pulseIn(DATA_PIN, HIGH);
  if (!(highDurationBeginning > 100 && highDurationBeginning < 450))
    return false;
  unsigned long lowDurationBeginning = pulseIn(DATA_PIN, LOW);
  if(!(lowDurationBeginning > 6000 && lowDurationBeginning < 8000))
    return false;
  
  while (i < maxCount) {
    unsigned long highDuration = pulseIn(DATA_PIN, HIGH);
    unsigned long lowDuration = pulseIn(DATA_PIN, LOW);
    if(((highDuration < 350 && highDuration > 120) || (highDuration > 500 && highDuration < 1000)) &&
        ((lowDuration < 350 && lowDuration > 120) || (lowDuration > 500 && lowDuration < 1000)))
        {
    highDurations[i] = highDuration;
    lowDurations[i] = lowDuration;
    
    i ++;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for(int j = 0; j < i; j ++)
  {
    Serial.println(String(j) + " : " + String(highDurations[j]) + " , " + String(lowDurations[j]));
    delay(100);
  }
  
  return true;
}




Data I sent
Data I received












I discover the following relationship between the data I sent and I received:








i.e., if I sent (600, 200) at first, just after the preamble, I get 600 on the 9th high value I read, and 200 on the 17th low value I read. These results are totally consistent. I checked them again and again, including sending (200, 600) at the beggining and 23 times (200, 200), I get 600 as 17th low value and everything else is around 200.
It also appears that the 24th HIGH value I send does not show up in the input I read. Furthermore, nothing I send seems to influence the 17th HIGH value in the received input, which is marked as "???" in the image above. I suspect I may have missed something here.

Something is out of sync for the encoder/decoder protocol to work.

I request a bit more info: what kind of MCU runs this code? Are you it's fast enough for this task? Can you try it with a faster one?
What is the clock speed for the encoder? Have you triple-checked the timing values against that?

I use arduino uno and nodemcu esp 8266 (powering rf receiver with 5v). Results are same. I will try a few thing tomorrow. For example I might try to catch first preamble sent. If this is caused by some delays in the receiver side, data I get must be a preamble and some parts of the data I guess

I found an Arduino library that decodes these remotes, and if your protocol is similar, I have a possible clue. From RCSwitch.cpp in the library, there is this comment describing how a logic '1' and logic '0' are transmitted over the air:
Sync bit: 
       _
      | |_______________________________ (don't count the vertical bars)
"0" bit:
       _
      | |___
"1" bit:
       ___
      |   |_

If this is the case, and your transmitter is sending more than one 24-bit packet of data (e.g. a sequence or repeating the same value), you might have an issue with your pulseIn function. From the Arduino documentation:

... if value is HIGH, pulseIn() waits for the pin to go from LOW to
HIGH, starts timing, then waits for the pin to go LOW and stops
timing.

For each bit, it looks like you mean to capture the high and low time.
      while (i < maxCount) {
        unsigned long highDuration = pulseIn(DATA_PIN, HIGH);
        unsigned long lowDuration = pulseIn(DATA_PIN, LOW);
        // error checking
        highDurations[i] = highDuration;
        lowDurations[i] = lowDuration;

For an example sequence, this is what I think might be going on. When you run the pulseIn(HIGH), it waits for the signal to be LOW, then transition to a HIGH state, and then return back to LOW. When you follow that up with pulseIn(LOW), it must wait for the LOW signal to go high before it can start measuring the pulse width. You could probably get rid of this issue by just calling pulseIn(HIGH) and skipping pulseIn(LOW), assuming that's what's going on.
I drew what I think is going on, with thesig_in signal representing the "over-the-air" value. Each bit period is marked by the bits, and 5 whole bits are shown. I think you're wanting to get the time the signal is high and the time the signal is low for each bit period, shown in the "expected" row. However, I think you're getting effectively jibberish because the pulseIn function is running on something like every other pulse.

Wavedrom code for fun:
{signal: [
  {name: 'sig_in',     wave: '010..1..010..10..1..01'},
  {name: 'bit',     wave: 'x3...5...3...5...3...5', data: "bit_1 bit_2 bit_3 bit_4 bit_5"},
  {name: 'expected', wave: 'x33..5..533..55..3..3x', data: "200H 600L 600H 200L 200H 600L 200H 600L 600H 200L"},
  {name: 'received', wave: 'x....3..xx3..xxxx5..x.', data: "600H 600L 600H"}
],
  config: { hscale: 0 }
  }


This sounds reasonable, I forget to note that my transmitters are indeed sending more than one 24-bit data unit; otherwise, it would break the universal law of reason and disrupt the cause-effect relationship! I will test it today, and give feedback.

It worked! I simply calculated the high and low durations by capturing the current time as micro seconds before and after entering a while loop where the pin state was HIGH and LOW, respectively.

Auchy. I spotted that issue after 5 minutes of reading the code, then interpreted the documentation as it won't havea problem with the pin already being HIGH. Should have checked the source code

I believe you are working with Arduino, before looking for errors inside the program, many people neglect a common issue with the hardware, I used to work on several R&D projects related to ocean technology (gov.def) and generally, we do not go with RF when it comes to sea-based, but for special cases and low range cases we do that, but with an enclosure suitable for the depth and to cancel out the dielectric constant of the salt water; which slightly increases the amplitude and we get our desired output, this application is used where sonic waves or another type of generic ocean-tech communication cannot be used.
Here the dielectric constant can also be considered noise for RF, for you it could be other Radio waves or some other environmental issue.
I would suggest aluminum or other metal enclosures generally.
You could try adjusting the power of the pulse or duration of the pulse, checking the receiver's sensitivity, or trying with other RF modules or alternate libraries.
Try modifying the program to return true only after reading all bits successfully ;
Try modifying the pulse limits, for example:
if (((highDuration < 400 && highDuration > 100) || (highDuration > 500 && highDuration < 1200)) &&
        ((lowDuration < 400 && lowDuration > 100) || (lowDuration > 500 && lowDuration < 1200))) {
        // Decode the duration into bits (this part is missing in your code)
        data |= (highDuration > 500 ? (1 << (maxCount - 1 - i)) : 0); // Simple example
        i++;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

Does your transmitter and receiver are on the same protocol? for example, some work with AFHDS, and some boards use AFHDS-2a; when you try to interface them, it won't work.
Also, make sure both run at the same frequency and clock, some modules are very sensitive even a slight value change won't work.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
